# WP7 imaging library

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, image-processing

I am trying to find a pure C# library with basic image processing functionality.
I need all morphological operations and edge detection.

I can't find something that will run on WP7(only managed code thanks to MS).

Is there anything out there or I have to implement my own one?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [Lead Tools](http://www.leadtools.com/sdk/silverlight/windows-phone.htm)?

Answer (score 0):

Have a [look at .NET Image Tools](http://imagetools.codeplex.com/releases/view/53740) it has been made available for the Windows Phone too.

Comment: I found this one but it doesn't support morphological operations.

Comment: Indeed but as far as I can see it is a better start to add the logic to this library than to start from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Lead Tool is not open source, I need free library just like Nokia Imaging SDK.